# How to connect to documentDB using karate?

Tags: karate, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

We have collections in documentDb to which I connect using the compass interface, but now I have to write test cases for it in karate and can't find a away to connect to documentDB. Is there any way please help!.